# New or old Git public key

Tags: git, github

New to Git.
I already have git installed from another company I worked at. If I already have git installed and have a public do I need to generate a new public key if I'm working in another company. Or does the public key just represent your machine.
Not sure I understand what exactly the public key is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSH keypair represents your identity, identified by either an email address (convenient) or a username@machine pair (inconvenient). You should generate new keys if you have a new corporate email address; *technically*(*), you can decide whether or not to link it with your GitHub profile, which supports several keys per user.

(*) I'm not a lawyer, this is not legal advice, and I'm not sure whether you're allowed to have multiple GitHub accounts. Check their terms of use.

Comment: The key is not *linked* to the email, the email is simply a comment on the key to help you identify it.

Comment: It's also not linked to the machine, either.

Answer (score 1):

A keypair is essentially just a password, albeit a more secure one (if you put a passphrase on it).  You do not **need** more than one key, ever.  If you wish to have more than one key, or to stop using an old one, that's entirely your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the private key was stored on a machine at your previous company then you should definitely change it. That key *is* you as far as bit streams and access protocols are concerned. It should be private to you.

If your git hub repos aren't that important (are they public anyway, & do you have local copies?) then you won't care half as much.

Just because you have nothing to hide doesn't mean you have nothing to protect ;-)